# How to implement slice_after (or group certain elements with certain subsequent ones) in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, enumerable, slice

The [`Enumerable#slice_before`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before) method is quite useful, and it does exactly what it says on the tin - slice an array before an element if a certain condition on the element is met. For example, I am using it to group certain numbers to the following ones.

In my case, the IDs `0xF0` to `0xFB` should be grouped with the IDs that come after them, including multiple of these IDs in a row (they are "modifier" flags in the thing I'm making). I'm doing it like this:

```
# example code (for SSCCE)
code = '00FF1234F0AAF0BBF0CCCCF3F4F5AAAAAA'.split('').each_slice(2).map{|n| n.join.to_i 16 }

# grouping the modifiers (more may be added later, so array is used)
code = code.slice_before {|tkn| ![*0xF0..0xFB].include? tkn }.to_a
```

The result of `code` after this is

```
[[0], [255], [18], [52, 240], [170, 240], [187, 240], [204], [204, 243, 244, 245], [170], [170], [170]]
```

However, the desired result is

```
[[0], [255], [18], [52], [240, 170], [240, 187], [240, 204], [204], [243, 244, 245, 170], [170], [170]]
```

I found [this entry on bugs.ruby-lang.org](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9071), and the response was

> The main reason [that this is not implemented] is no one requested.
>
> I have not enough time to implement it now.

Therefore, how can I implement it myself?

Comment: Why is it `[243, 244, 245]` in your desired output and not `[243, 244, 245, 170]`? `245` (= `0xF5`) lies between `0xF0` and `0xFB`, so `170` should be in that array, shouldn't it?

Comment: @tessi Because of a typo ;) fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the elegant one-liner I'd like to have, but this gets the job done :)

```
target = []
code.each do |i|
  # if there is a previous element and it was one of the "modifiers"
  if target.last && [*0xF0..0xFB].include?(target.last.last)
    # append it to the current subarray
    target.last << i
  else
    # otherwise, append a new subarray
    target << [i]
  end
end
```

You'll find the desired array in `target` with `code` being unchanged.

Comment: Thanks! I've edited in some basic comments to help future visitors understand the code.

Answer (score 2):

[`Enumerable#slice_after`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-trunk/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_after) is available if you are using Ruby 2.2.0 or later, so you can just use it:

```
modifiers = 0xF0..0xFB
hex_code = '00FF1234F0AAF0BBF0CCCCF3F4F5AAAAAA'
bytes = [hex_code].pack('H*').bytes
code = bytes.slice_after { |b| !modifiers.include? b }.to_a
p code  # => [[0], [255], [18], [52], [240, 170], ...
```